# Update multiple records using ecto 2.0

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I could insert multiple records in ecto 2.0:

```
iex(1)> categories = [%{name: "stackoverflow", url: "stackoverflow.com"}]

iex(2)> App.Repo.insert_all App.Category, categories
```

Is it possible to update multiple records at once?

```
iex(1) > category = App.Repo.all(App.Category) |> hd

iex(2) > changeset = App.Category.changeset(category, %{name: "test"})

iex(3)> App.Repo.insert_all App.Category, [changeset]
```

I've a scenario where I've to insert or update categories everyday after crawling external pages. Seems like there is `Multi` feature in Ecto 2.0. Any pointers on how to go about this?

Comment: But update_all (is based in a query) is very different of insert_all (is based in a list) ... Dont exist one update_all based in a list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as there is an [insert_all/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.0-rc.5/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3) function, there is also an [update_all/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.0-rc.5/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update_all/3) function. `update_all/3` takes a Queryable (`%MyApp.SomeModel{}` or a query), a Keyword List of updates (`[name: "John"]`), and an optional Keyword List of options.

Comment: But update_all (is based in a query) is very different of insert_all (is based in a list) ... Dont exist one update_all based in a list?

Comment: @Nuno_Coletiv Sounds like you're looking for an upsert. See the Upsert section of https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3

Comment: I read about that but when tried send one list with object with id and without id ...  the insert_all always try insert because when the object in list have id filled give me the error "This id already exists" ?!?!

Comment: Sounds like a worthwhile question to post on SO, with as many details about what you're doing as possible.